# asp.net mvc adding data to database programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a problem with adding data to my database. I have table for book, users and borrows. So, when user is logged in application and pick book, I want to add new data to borrows table. I thought it should be something like this(I call this method where click on chosen book):

```
public ActionResult AddIt([Bind(Include = "BorrowId,BorrowDate,GiveBackDate,BookId,UserId")] Borrows br))
{
    br.BorrowDate = DateTime.Now;
    br.BookId = int.Parse(Session["BookId"].ToString());
    br.UserId = int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString());
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.borrows.Add(br);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Getting UserId and BookId works, but there is something wrong while call this method. I got "Can't find resource" error. So, how should look that method? GiveBackDate is Nullable and I want it to be null when create record.

EDIT: I rebuilded project and that error disapeared.. But code still doesn't work properly. Seems like asp did not count BorrowIds. If database is empty I can save one record. But if one record is saved, next one goes with id 0 and generates error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BORROWS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Borrows'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

Error at 84 row:

84:             {

85:                 db.Borrows.Add(br);

**86:                 db.SaveChanges();**

87:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
88:             }

I call AddIt here, in BookController:

```
public ActionResult borrow(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("AddIt", "Borrows");
}
```

Comment: You need to add the error to your question.  Call ToString on the exception and paste it into an [edit]

Comment: What line actually causes the exception and what are the full exception details?

Comment: An HTTP 404 normally means there is a routing problem.  An HTTP 500 is the standard for when the code is running but an error is thrown at some point.

Comment: I also don't know why you are using session data for this.  A standard form post would be easier.  Is there a page where the user clicks 'Checkout' which then causes the form to post?

Comment: Problem is either with routing or your url/method, 404 means this function isn't even being found at the URL you are using.

Comment: One other possibility could be the AddIt action result is located in another controller. In which case you can add a method in the original controller to do the redirection the other controller while maintaining your session.

Comment: Show us the code that makes this request to an AddIt action in a BorrowsController.

Comment: I shoved request to AddIt. But I still don't know why asp didn't count my borrow Ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason of violation primary key error. When I was creating database, I didn't add an IDENTITY property to my primary key BorrowID column. So, id should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Borrows] (
    [BorrowId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the URL is correct. Controller, action and routing-wise
2. Make sure you're actually making a HTTP Post, since the action is mapped to a Post verb only.